# Iframe is not displaying when copied on to new site

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm having trouble with a twitter iframe that isn't displaying, the code has been copied from another site where it is working in almost exactly the same markup.

I've checked in Litmus and the problem is there on all browsers.

The page I'm trying to make it work is [here](http://www.myetouches.com/dell/login) where the twitter feed should appear on the right of the login form.

The page which it's working from is [here](https://www.eiseverywhere.com/cust_login.php?accountid=914)

For reference, the iframe is at line 244 of the page source.

```
#twitter {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    margin: 25px;
    display: inline-block;

<div id="twitter">
    <iframe id="twitter-widget-0" 
        scrolling="no"
        frameborder="0"
        allowtransparency="true"
        class="twitter-timeline twitter-timeline-rendered"
        allowfullscreen=""
        style="border: none;
        max-width: 100%;
        min-width: 180px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: static;
        visibility: visible;
        width: 400px;"
        title="Twitter Timeline"
        height="500">
    </iframe>

    <script id="twitter-wjs"
        src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    <script>
    <script>
         ! function (d, s, id) {
             var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
             p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
             if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                 js = d.createElement(s);
                 js.id = id;
                 js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
    </script>
</div>
```

Some changes between the pages are that due to factors out of my control, everything is wrapped in a table. Which is the only difference between the structure of the pages that I can really think of, although I don't think that would affect an iframe.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try this?

```
<div id="twitter">
        <a class="twitter-timeline"
    data-dnt="true"
    href="https://twitter.com/etouches"
    data-widget-id="570513672875671552">
    Tweets by @etouches
</a>
<script>
    !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
    </div>
```